# What is the meaning of ramification?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

What is the meaning of the sentence--"Let $p$ be a prime that ramifies" ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_(mathematics)#In_algebraic_number_theory

Comment: It would greatly improve your Question to say where you found this statement, and as you should anticipate, the meaning of such sentences depends on the context you left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be a number field and let $O_k$ be the ring of integers in $k$. It is a theorem that every ideal $I$ in $O_k$ can be factored into a product of prime ideals uniquely up to ordering the factors. Let $p$ be a prime integer (sometimes called a ``rational prime"). Then $pO_k$ is an ideal in $O_k$ -- call it $(p)$. By the theorem, there exist a non-negative integer $r$, non-negative integers $e_1,...,e_r$, and prime ideals $P_1,...,P_r$ such that $(p)=P_1^{e_1}...P_r^{e_r}$. We say that $p$ is ramified in $k$ if any of the $e_i>1$. Otherwise (i.e. if all the $e_i=1$), we say that $p$ is unramified in $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the simplest example : $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ then $\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus it is sufficient to look at the prime ideals containing $p$ for each prime $p$ :

- $(2) = (1+i)(1+i)$ is ramified,
- if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ then $(p) = (a+ib)(a-ib)$ for some $a,b, a^2+b^2= p$,
- if  $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ then $(p)$ is a prime ideal.

Similarly, since $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ :

- $x^2+1 \equiv (x+1)^2 \bmod 2$ has a double root,
- if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ then $x^2+1 \equiv (x+a)(x-a) \bmod p$
- otherwise if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ then $x^2+1$ is irreducible $\bmod p$.

The theory is explained there : [Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions)